# Nesting sort() in Python, simultaneous multi-attributed function sorting

Tags: python, sorting, nested

I have a list of drones, that goes like this:

**INPUT**

```
[['Spider', 'NYC', '15', '1500', '600', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:30'], ['Falcon', 'NJ', '25', '1500', '500', '10', '2019-11-05', '15:30'], ['Snake', 'NYC', '10', '2000', '500', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:20'], ['Lion', 'NYC', '25', '2500', '200', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:40'], ['Shark', 'BRX', '15', '1500', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'], ['Leopard', 'NJ', '20', '2000', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'], ['Dove', 'BRX', '10', '1500', '100', '1', '2019-11-05', '15:50']]
```

And I need to sort this list in order to have, say, for example, the ones that have "NYC" in them come first. For that, I have this lambda function:

```
drone_list.sort(key= lambda drone: (drone[1]!=Area))
```

where *Area* is simply the string I want to sort it by (if I want the ones from NYC to come first, I'd swap *Area* with "NYC".

But I also need to sort the list, simultaneously, in a way that the ones with the earliest timestamps (index no. 7) come first. For example, I need the "NYC" drones to be first in the list, but I also need *those "NYC" drones* to be sorted by their timestamps. Expecting something like this:

```
[['Snake', 'NYC', '10', '2000', '500', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:20'], ['Spider', 'NYC', '15', '1500', '600', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:30'], ['Lion', 'NYC', '25', '2500', '200', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:40'], ...[other drones]]
```

And to sort them by their timestamps, I have another little function that goes like this:

`sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[7], '%H:%M'))`

Both those functions work, so now I'll explain my problem: I can't run them one after the other, because if I do, with the second function I run I'll just be undoing whatever *sort* came first, which is not what I want.

To clarify, and I apologize for the confusion: I want a list sorted by more than one lambda function. I have even split these into little separately defined functions but I still cannot run them simultaneously in a way that running one of them doesn't undo the previous ones.
I know I can get something similar done with *operand.itemgetter()*, however, that doesn't take functions.

Essentially, I need to know how to run multiple lambda functions in the same *sort()*, or, if I can't, then how to bypass this.

*EDIT: Some have told me to first sort by timestamps then by name, which worked, but the thing is that for the sake of simplicity on this post I didn't mention that I'll have to sort by a lot more attributes. I'll have to sort the drones first by Area (index 1), then by time (index 7), then by autonomy (in reverse, index 5), then by distance travelled (in reverse, index 4), and finally, by alphanumeric order of their name (index 0). So that trick won't help me for those two, given that I have to sort the drones by that exact order of attributes...

Comment: sort by time, then by area should work. since sort is stable.

Comment: Sort by timestamp first and then by area.  The timestamp sorting should be preserved for drones from NYC.  See Sort Stability and Complex Sorts [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/sorting.html).

Comment: That would work, but for me in this case, please read the edit :/

Comment: Can I ask why you need to *sort* by area? When you say sort, you're implying that you need to enforce a particular order of *all* elements, but when you talk about how you plan to use this implementation, you show that you use this as `drone[1]!=Area`. Seems like instead of sorting you could instead partition your data by placing it in a dictionary with keys of the area, and then sort each element in the dictionary by date, which intrinsically has an objective order (chronological).

Comment: @MichaelGreen sorry for not explaining. I need to sort by *Area* because this is going to take part in a delivery system kind of project, so I need that list to always be the same, just with the drones in different positions. Nevertheless, could you please provide an example? Sorry, it's just that you might be right and I might be blind here.

Comment: It's fine, seems like someone else was able to give you a more complete answer thought so we'll leave it at that. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by tuple `(k[1] != 'NYC', datetime.strptime(k[7], '%H:%M'))`, where `k` is your data entry.

Explanation:

`k[1] != 'NYC'` is True for everything except `NYC` -> so for NYC this is `False`, that way `NYC` entries come first

`datetime.strptime(k[7], '%H:%M')` simply converts the entry 7 to time, so lowest time comes first

NOTE: If your time is in '%H:%M' format (00-23:00-59), it's even not necessary to convert the string to datetime.

```
data = [['Spider', 'NYC', '15', '1500', '600', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:30'], ['Falcon', 'NJ', '25', '1500', '500', '10', '2019-11-05', '15:30'], ['Snake', 'NYC', '10', '2000', '500', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:20'], ['Lion', 'NYC', '25', '2500', '200', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:40'], ['Shark', 'BRX', '15', '1500', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'], ['Leopard', 'NJ', '20', '2000', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'], ['Dove', 'BRX', '10', '1500', '100', '1', '2019-11-05', '15:50']]

from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

# sort by NYC first, time first
pprint(sorted(data, key=lambda k: (k[1] != 'NYC', datetime.strptime(k[7], '%H:%M'))))
```

Prints:

```
[['Snake', 'NYC', '10', '2000', '500', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:20'],
 ['Spider', 'NYC', '15', '1500', '600', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:30'],
 ['Lion', 'NYC', '25', '2500', '200', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:40'],
 ['Falcon', 'NJ', '25', '1500', '500', '10', '2019-11-05', '15:30'],
 ['Shark', 'BRX', '15', '1500', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'],
 ['Leopard', 'NJ', '20', '2000', '800', '20', '2019-11-05', '15:45'],
 ['Dove', 'BRX', '10', '1500', '100', '1', '2019-11-05', '15:50']]
```

Comment: Thank you. To me, this seems the most logical approach and thanks for the thorough explanation, but how could I add more attributes with this method?

Comment: @Hasake If it's possible, you can add more entries to the tuple. Now the tuple has 2 elements (boolean and time), but it can have more.

Comment: Use `k[1] != 'NYC'`. Do not use `is` here as it may appear to work in this example because the identical string literals were interned at compile time, it will not work when new strings with the same content are created via other paths.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I think I got it. Just to rectify, for example, to then sort them by autonomy, could I do something like: `sorted(data, key=lambda k: (k[1] != 'NYC', datetime.strptime(k[7], '%H:%M'), -k[5])))`

Comment: @Hasake Yes, but make sure to convert `k[5]` to int first. The `-` sign signifies that it will go in descending order (from biggest to lowest)

Comment: Alright!! It all seems to be working, except the last parameter which is literally just sorting them by their name (index 0), I get the message that "list" isn't callable. Thank you so much, seriously.

Comment: @AndrejKesely How do I make it sort the elements by index 0 in the end, as another element of the lambda tuple?

Comment: @Hasake Do you mean alphabeticaly? Simply put it into the tuple...